# Polynomial Curve Fitting with Excel

Tags: excel

I am trying to make an excel polynomial curve fitting with excel, but it does not working for me.

I am using the following function: `=Index(LINEST(B7:B15;A7:A15^{1;2;3});1;1)` but the excel say it is wrong.

I use semicolon for argument separation.

[Polynomial Curve Fitting with Excel](https://web.cecs.pdx.edu/%7Eeas199/A/notes/14/polynomial_curve_fit_notes.pdf)

[image]

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem.  Please edit your question to actually **copy/paste** the formula from your worksheet into your question, instead of just typing it in.  Also, please inform as to your system separators (thousands, decimal, list) under your Windows Regional Settings.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld I have just reedited my question

Comment: This result: `#VALUE!` is different from what you reported in your original question, as is the separator you now show your array constant.  Depending on your Windows region, it might be better as `{1\2\3}`  If that doesn't work, please share your Region.  The `;` will result in a vertical array; whereas the `\\`` separator should result in a horizontal array, which is what you want for the `LINEST` function looking for a polynomial curve. This is the case when `,` is the decimal separator.